# Custom search/lookup using multiple fields in Excel - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to search in Excel with multiple search fields.

For example, I have:

- A master database sheet with all the age, height, and weight values.
- Another search sheet where users can input age, height, and weight. The values from the master sheet are returned.

[image: Sample screenshot]

Currently in my VBA, I am writing a conditional statement to check for every search condition (in my case there would be 7 conditional statements).

Is there a better way of doing this? I would prefer to not keep adding if-statements as the search fields increases from 3.

Comment: As you asked "Is there a better way of doing this?"
Yes, Microsoft Access will do all that easily. Of course, the learning curve is steep but if you expect recurring tasks like this it'll be worthwhile

Comment: PeakPeak: Why suggest Access - an entirely different app that the user may not even have access to - when the user can easily accomplish this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for exact matches (all 3 values match) then best way is to add a column on the database that concatenates the values. Then you concatenate the 3 search values and only search one column.

If you want to return all individual matches a quick way would be to use an auto filter on the database, that way you filter each column and copy paste the visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Filter functionality in Excel will let you do exactly this, and you can easily call it from VBA. See http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html for a great set of tutorials on this.